# How can I stream data from React Native webview to React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

I would like to save large files to the device disk in React Native. To do this one option is to send the whole file in Base64 using the `onMessage`, but for large files this is not the best option.

Is there a way to stream the file to be saved from WebView to React Native?